# Send jQuery POST to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: jquery

I have a web API written in C#. Here is a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("notepad/")]
public Notepad AddNote(Notepad note)
{
    note.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _Context.Add(note);
    _Context.SaveChanges();
    return note;
}
```

Here is a POST request sent from Postman (and it works):

[image]

Now I want to send this request using jQuery. Here is my jQuery code that should do the same as in Postman but in some reason controller doesn't receive **Title** and **Message** (in controller it's null but I checked that in jQuery it has some value). jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44326/notepad',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
                Title: document.getElementById('for-title').value,
                Message: document.getElementById('for-message').value
        })
        });
```

Comment: You're sending form data in Postman and JSON data in jQuery. I assume your backend doesn't know how to parse JSON data, and fails because of that.

Comment: Add [FromBody] and see if that works (fixes this issue for me)  Notepad AddNote([FromBody] Notepad note)

Comment: Ah I forgot! Thank you. [FromBody] solved this.

Comment: Have you tried without stringify?  ie `data: { Title: ... , Message: ... },`

Comment: @TheMoon no problem.

Comment: @TheMoon, what you originally posted here worked for me. Perhaps your model class was defined with fields instead of properties, etc. But in any case what caused the problem is not in the code you posted here. Voting to close.

Comment: @derloopkat my model has properties. By adding [FromBody] I was able to solve this problem.

Comment: Do not accept wrong answers - it misleads other users (and if you had bothered to try that code, you would know that it does not work)

Answer (score 0):

AS addNote action receive notepad object so you donot need to stringyfy and make sure AddNote action parameter name and ajax data passing object name should be same i.e note.

try this, hopeful this will help you.

```
var note ={
                Title: document.getElementById('for-title').value,
                Message: document.getElementById('for-message').value
        };

        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44326/notepad',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: note 
        });
```

Comment: @The Moon Try this

Comment: Thank you I already solved this with @Chris Dixon advice. I'll also use your code because it looks better than mine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @The Moon. please upvote if this answer helpful for you.